# Weird chars in the beginning of SEF url

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, sef, custom-component

I'm developing router to my custom component. Almost everything is working ok. But with one url I have problem.
It seems to be build properly by build method:

**dodaj-zdjecia/addphotos.html**

But after following this url it is redirected to:

**/%EF%BB%BF/dodaj-zdjecia/addphotos.html**

And of course I get 404 error.

I tried almost everything...
What could be the reason?

Comment: You're using special characters in your alias. Don't do that.

Comment: No, I was not using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. In my router file I was including model. And it's model file had BOM sygnature included. It was causing this error...

Comment: Thanks for coming back and putting the solution up. I'd go one step further and mark this as the accepted answer.